# Is it possible to have more waypoints in Maps.app on OSX?

Tags: macos, maps

Is it possible to have waypoints, or multiple destinations, when getting route directions in the Maps.app on OSX Mavericks?

I would like to change the route like one can by dragging the route in Google Maps, or by adding a waypoint of a city I want the route to go through.

Is this accomplishable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, so far! Hopefully, apple will add that option to the next update?

Comment: Your note regarding the "next" update is still entirely relevant. Two or three versions later, we are still hoping for this.

Comment: Hello from 6 years in the future.  Still relevant!  Just installed Google Maps on my iPhone again to get this :).

Answer (score -1):

I just checked into this, and I cannot find a way to make these types of adjustments.  Pitty!